# getJSON is returning XML from this API

Tags: jquery, api, jsonp

This is returning an XML file and normal .get is not allowed, what am I doing wrong? 
Here's their guide: http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip/help/operations/GetRoutes

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
 var url = "http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip/Routes?callback=?";
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            $('#content').append(data);
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *explicitly* request the response format to be JSON, by adding `format=json` to the query string:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  var url = "http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip/Routes?format=json&callback=?";
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $("#content").append(data[i].Description + "<br />");
    }
  });    
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yhqdD/)**.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going crazy.